# Does Oracle 11gR2 is supported on RHEL 8 or Oracle Linux 8?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, linux, redhat

Oracle (afaik) did not updated their compatibility matrix yet. Can I run Oracle 11gR2 (which still is in extended suporte) in the new OS?

Comment: They never will update it to be certified on RHEL 8  - 11g is not even supported now unless you pay a fortune for extended support.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can run it without any issues but it is not supported by Oracle. As Phil suggests in his comment this combination will never be supported as you are mixing an almost out of support database ([extended](https://mikedietrichde.com/2015/10/17/extended-support-fee-for-oracle-11-2-0-4-waived-until-may-31-2017-extended-support-until-dec-2020/) is over on December 2020) with a just added Linux release.

Best solution is use Oracle 12.2 which, in my experience, is a minimal problem migration target for most applications using Oracle 11.  The 12.2 release allows an [easy upgrade](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/upgrade/overview/upgrading-oracle-database-wp-122-3403093.pdf) to Oracle 18 or 19 when the time comes.

Comment: Go to 19c, it’s available for Linux and the terminal patchhset (LTS Update) for 12.2

Comment: @eckes sure, but test first, you never know what code structures like calls to file operations are not known